# ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2: Why link for new WFS Server does not work in ArcGIS Pro but works on QGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, wfs, server, url

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2 and would like to connect a new WFS server to the software. The link works in QGIS 3.22.16.

Would it work in ArcGIS Pro?

Under the "Insert" menu, I clicked on "Connect", expanded "server" and chose "new WFS server". I pasted the link in the URL server and used my username and password. I tried but still got this error message.

[image]other servers (OGC API, WCS server)

Comment: If I try to open the [capabilities url](https://geo-cumberland.highway-iams.uk/geoserver/cumberland/ows?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetCapabilities) in a browser, it says Not Found, (rather than Unauthorized). Are you sure about the address?

Comment: Just a small nitpick: The software is called ArcGIS Pro, and version 3.2.1 is not out yet, AFAIK

Comment: Sorry it's Arcpro version 3.1.2. The link works in QGIS, it is not from the link.

Comment: Berend. We took off the word "cumberland" from the link. We got a connection however we can't have access to the data as they are placed one folder below (cumberland folder). Any idea what could cause that issue in ArcGIS pro? Again we tried the link in QGIS then it works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, without `cumberland` I can see valid WFS response, too. But there aren't any layers in that [capabilities](https://geo-cumberland.highway-iams.uk/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetCapabilities) document

Comment: I don't know what types of authorization ArcGIS and GeoServer support when using a WFS service. Maybe they're not compatible.

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.